FocusVisualStyle is not shown initially when a new window is opened
I have a custom window, with a control template:
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="THEME_ButtonFocusStyle">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="2"
                            BorderBrush="Red"
                            Margin="-4"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyWindow}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyWindow}">
                    <Grid>
                        <AdornerDecorator>
                            <StackPanel Margin="30">
                                <Button x:Name="btn"
                                        Content="no visible focus initially"
                                        Width="100"
                                        Margin="10"
                                        FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource THEME_ButtonFocusStyle}"/>
                                <Button Content="other button"                                  
                                        Width="100"
                                        Margin="10"
                                        FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource THEME_ButtonFocusStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

If I open the window I want the first button to have the keyboard focus along with the keyboard focus visualization:
public class MyWindow : Window { }

//-------------------

var window = new MyWindow();
window.Loaded += (o, args) =>
{
    window.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        var btn = WPFUtils.GetFirstChildWithName<Button>((DependencyObject)o, "btn"); // just some helper method which finds the button control on the window in a recursive way
        Keyboard.Focus(btn);
    }));
};
window.ShowDialog();

It seems the keyboard focus is successfully applied, but the focus visual style is not rendered.

If I pressed ALT suddenly the focus visualization is renderd.
If I press TAB the focus is correctly shown on the second button.

and if I press TAB a second time, it will be visible on the initial button.

Does someone know how to enable the focus visualization when the window opens?
Setting the logical focus in addition did not help as well:
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(window, btn);

Update:
Even if the button has the correct focus visualization eventually, if I click outside of the window, for example on the taskbar and click back on the window title bar, the keyboard focus visualization is again not shown, even though the button has "IsKeyboardFocused" set to true...

As you noticed, setting focus is not enough to show FocusVisualStyle. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/9534396/3137337 It ultimately depends on InputManager.Current.MostRecentInputDevice and so, if you stick to show FocusVisualStyle, I think you will need to somehow trick InputManager.

Intuitively, a  "-4" Margin (all around) would / could / should clip an element with a "2" BorderThickness.
